# Google Ventures Side Nav

Tags: server-side, dreamhost

I have been trying to figure out how the Google Venture Side-Nav works. I was able to get it to work on my computer locally, but it does not work once loaded onto Dreamhost's server at http://bikingagainstcancer.com/.

I wondered if anyone had any suggestions for how to get the nav bar to collapse? Any help would be appreciated! I am very new to coding, so please let me know what other information would be helpful and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the check you have in `scripts.js:129`

```js
if (isHome() || !collapsableNav) { return; }
```

`isHome()` returns `true` on the frontpage, so the test passes, and the function returns.

Comment: Thank you! I created a second page not named index and it now works perfectly!

Comment: Funny. Merry christmas!